# read in bash on whitespace-delimited file without empty fields collapsing

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read a multi-line tab-separated file in bash. The format is such that empty fields are expected. Unfortunately, the shell is collapsing together field separators which are next to each other, as so:

```
# IFS=$'\t'
# read one two three <<<$'one\t\tthree'
# printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
<one> <three> <>
```

...as opposed to the desired output of `<one> <> <three>`.

Can this be resolved without resorting to a separate language (such as awk)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with some niceties:

- input data from wherever becomes a pseudo-2D array in the main code (avoiding a common problem where the data is only available within one stage of a pipeline).
- no use of awk, tr, or other external progs
- a get/put accessor pair to hide the hairier syntax
- works on tab-delimited lines by using param matching instead of IFS=

The code.  `file_data` and `file_input` are just for generating input as though from a external command called from the script.  `data` and `cols` could be parameterized for the `get` and `put` calls, etc, but this script doesn't go that far.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_data=( $'\t\t'       $'\t\tbC'     $'\tcB\t'     $'\tdB\tdC'   \
            $'eA\t\t'     $'fA\t\tfC'   $'gA\tgB\t'   $'hA\thB\thC' )
file_input () { printf '%s\n' "${file_data[@]}" ; }  # simulated input file
delim=$'\t'

# the IFS=$'\n' has a side-effect of skipping blank lines; acceptable:
OIFS="$IFS" ; IFS=$'\n' ; oset="$-" ; set -f
lines=($(file_input))                    # read the "file"
set -"$oset" ; IFS="$OIFS" ; unset oset  # cleanup the environment mods.

# the read-in data has (rows * cols) fields, with cols as the stride:
data=()
cols=0
get () { local r=$1 c=$2 i ; (( i = cols * r + c )) ; echo "${data[$i]}" ; }
put () { local r=$1 c=$2 i ; (( i = cols * r + c )) ; data[$i]="$3" ; }

# convert the lines from input into the pseudo-2D data array:
i=0 ; row=0 ; col=0
for line in "${lines[@]}" ; do
    line="$line$delim"
    while [ -n "$line" ] ; do
        case "$line" in
            *${delim}*) data[$i]="${line%%${delim}*}" ; line="${line#*${delim}}" ;;
            *)          data[$i]="${line}"            ; line=                     ;;
        esac
        (( ++i ))
    done
    [ 0 = "$cols" ] && (( cols = i )) 
done
rows=${#lines[@]}

# output the data array as a matrix, using the get accessor
for    (( row=0 ; row < rows ; ++row )) ; do
   printf 'row %2d: ' $row
   for (( col=0 ; col < cols ; ++col )) ; do
       printf '%5s ' "$(get $row $col)"
   done
   printf '\n'
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./tabtest 
row  0:                   
row  1:                bC 
row  2:          cB       
row  3:          dB    dC 
row  4:    eA             
row  5:    fA          fC 
row  6:    gA    gB       
row  7:    hA    hB    hC
```

Comment: It might be worth using `set -f` before lines=($(file_input))

Comment: The effects without the -f are amusing, true, but not good, modifying it.

Comment: I have a more parameterized one at http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/software/pub/bash-arrays2d - but I think it's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 14):

#### Sure

---

```
IFS=,
echo $'one\t\tthree' | tr \\11 , | (
  read one two three
  printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
)
```

I've rearranged the example just a bit, but only to make it work in any Posix shell.

Update: Yeah, it seems that white space is special, at least if it's in IFS. See the second half of this paragraph from bash(1):

```
   The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and  splits  the
   results of the other expansions into words on these characters.  If IFS
   is unset, or its value is exactly <space><tab><newline>,  the  default,
   then  any  sequence  of IFS characters serves to delimit words.  If IFS
   has a value other than the default, then sequences  of  the  whitespace
   characters  space  and  tab are ignored at the beginning and end of the
   word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value  of  IFS  (an
   IFS whitespace character).  Any character in IFS that is not IFS white-
   space, along with any adjacent IFS whitespace  characters,  delimits  a
   field.   A  sequence  of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a
   delimiter.  If the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.
```

Comment: Is there something special about whitespace, then, that I need to choose a non-whitespace character (in your example, a comma) guaranteed never to be found in my data?

Comment: Good answer. Not using it myself as I don't like restricting the valid range of data unnecessary, but definitely worth an upvote.

Comment: Hmm, one idea might be to `tr(1)` the tabs into newlines and then issue three separate `read` calls. That should be a simple way to preserve all possible input characters but still process things in strict shell code.

Comment: right -- the tr thing is what I'm doing in the other answer to the question.

Comment: Doesn't the quoted verbiage mean that if you changed the IFS to just tab, then you'd get the required splitting behaviour?

Comment: @Jonathan: It says that a " *sequence* of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as *a* delimiter.", so no.

Comment: This answer is interesting but would break if data contains a comma (because the answer uses it as delimiter). If some other character is known to not appear in data, it may be used instead of the comma and that answer would succeed.

Comment: Using `IFS=$'\a'` works, and you probably don't have `\a` ([alarm bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)) in your input data.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make this work in a while loop, to process each line of a file with `tr` before the `read`.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was hoping for. Somehow missed that text in the man page.

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessary to use `tr`, but it is necessary that `IFS` is a non-whitespace character (otherwise multiples get collapsed to singles as you've seen).

```
$ IFS=, read -r one two three <<<'one,,three'
$ printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
<one> <> <three>

$ var=$'one\t\tthree'
$ var=${var//$'\t'/,}
$ IFS=, read -r one two three <<< "$var"
$ printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
<one> <> <three>

$ idel=$'\t' odel=','
$ var=$'one\t\tthree'
$ var=${var//$idel/$odel}
$ IFS=$odel read -r one two three <<< "$var"
$ printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
<one> <> <three>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the substitution can be done with PE

Comment: Using `IFS=$'\a'` works, and you probably don't have `\a` ([alarm bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)) in your input data.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a function which works around this issue. This particular implementation is particular about tab-separated columns and newline-separated rows, but that limitation could be removed as a straightforward exercise:

```
read_tdf_line() {
    local default_ifs=$' \t\n'
    local n line element at_end old_ifs
    old_ifs="${IFS:-${default_ifs}}"
    IFS=$'\n'

    if ! read -r line ; then
        return 1
    fi
    at_end=0
    while read -r element; do
        if (( $# > 1 )); then
            printf -v "$1" '%s' "$element"
            shift
        else
            if (( at_end )) ; then
                # replicate read behavior of assigning all excess content
                # to the last variable given on the command line
                printf -v "$1" '%s\t%s' "${!1}" "$element"
            else
                printf -v "$1" '%s' "$element"
                at_end=1
            fi
        fi
    done < <(tr '\t' '\n' <<<"$line")

    # if other arguments exist on the end of the line after all
    # input has been eaten, they need to be blanked
    if ! (( at_end )) ; then
        while (( $# )) ; do
            printf -v "$1" '%s' ''
            shift
        done
    fi

    # reset IFS to its original value (or the default, if it was
    # formerly unset)
    IFS="$old_ifs"
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
# read_tdf_line one two three rest <<<$'one\t\tthree\tfour\tfive'
# printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three" "$rest"; printf '\n'
<one> <> <three> <four       five>
```

Comment: If `IFS` was previously unset, why would you restore it to the default, instead of unsetting it again?

Comment: It doesn't fare well if the read line is more like `read one two three rest <<<$'\t\tthree\tfour\tfive'` - it relies heavily on non-null initial fields; empty fields throw the indexing off.

Comment: @chepner Ease-of-implementation; this way I don't need to have a way to represent the unset state.

Comment: Should the first line of the usage section be `# read_tdf_line one two three rest <<<$'one\t\tthree\tfour\tfive'` (correcting the function name)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fast and simple function I use that avoids calling external programs or restricting the range of input characters. It works in bash only (I guess).

If it is to allow for more variables than fields, though, it needs to be modified along Charles Duffy's answer.

```
# Substitute for `read -r' that doesn't merge adjacent delimiters.
myread() {
        local input
        IFS= read -r input || return $?
        while [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]; do
                IFS= read -r "$1" <<< "${input%%[$IFS]*}"
                input="${input#*[$IFS]}"
                shift
        done
        IFS= read -r "$1" <<< "$input"
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can just do `|| return`; `$?` is the default return value.

Comment: ...also, `[[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]` is a suboptimal way to write things; `while (( $# )); do` is shorter, whereas `while (( $# > 1 )); do` is clearer.

Comment: Thanks @charles-duffy.

Quotes around `$#` are only for the highlighting engine here, which otherwise interprets the # as introducing a comment.

Also, if you deal with very long lines it'd probably be faster to avoid the second pattern matching like this: 

`local len;` 

and then in the inner loop after the "`IFS=`" line: 

`len=${!1}; len=${#len}; input=${input:$len}`

Comment: It wasn't actually the quotes I was objecting to, but the use of `-gt`. Using a numeric-comparison operator in the general-purpose test context rather than using a math context hurts readability, as opposed to being able to use conventional math-centric operators.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the collapse of empty fields, you can use
any delimiter other than the IFS "whitespace" chars.

An example of how different delimiters would behave:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for delimiter in  $'\t'  ','  '|'  $'\377'  $'\x1f'  ;do
  line="one${delimiter}${delimiter}three"
  IFS=$delimiter read one two three <<<"$line"
  printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'
done

<one> <three> <>
<one> <> <three>
<one> <> <three>
<one> <> <three>
<one> <> <three>
```

Or to use the OP's original example:

```sh
IFS='|' read one two three <<<$(tr '\t' '|' <<<$'one\t\tthree')
printf '<%s> ' "$one" "$two" "$three"; printf '\n'

<one> <> <three>
```

Answer (score 0):

**bash 4+ with mapfile**

We know `\n` cannot appear inside a line. So we can convert all `\t` to `\n` and then read the result with `mapfile`.

```
printf $'11\t12\t13\n\t22\t23\n31\t32\t\n\t42\t' >data
```

```
mapfile -t rows <data
declare -p rows

for r in "${rows[@]}"; do
    mapfile -t row <<<"${r//$'\t'/$'\n'}"
    declare -p row
done
```

```
declare -a rows=([0]=$'11\t12\t13' [1]=$'\t22\t23' [2]=$'31\t32\t' [3]=$'\t42\t')
declare -a row=([0]="11" [1]="12" [2]="13")
declare -a row=([0]="" [1]="22" [2]="23")
declare -a row=([0]="31" [1]="32" [2]="")
declare -a row=([0]="" [1]="42" [2]="")
```

or:

```
while IFS= read -r row || [[ -n $row ]]; do
    mapfile -t row <<<"${row//$'\t'/$'\n'}"
    declare -p row
done <data
```

```
declare -a row=([0]="11" [1]="12" [2]="13")
declare -a row=([0]="" [1]="22" [2]="23")
declare -a row=([0]="31" [1]="32" [2]="")
declare -a row=([0]="" [1]="42" [2]="")
```

If required, the array elements can be assigned to simple variables.

---

**bash 3 with read**

Same idea but just using `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    row=()
    while IFS= read -r field; do
        row+=("$field")
    done <<<"${line//$'\t'/$'\n'}"
    declare -p row
done <data
```

```
declare -a row='([0]="11" [1]="12" [2]="13")'
declare -a row='([0]="" [1]="22" [2]="23")'
declare -a row='([0]="31" [1]="32" [2]="")'
declare -a row='([0]="" [1]="42" [2]="")'
```