# How to split a tab-delimited string in bash script WITHOUT collapsing blanks?

Tags: bash, split, csv

I have my string in `$LINE` and I want `$ITEMS` to be the array version of this, split on *single tabs* and *retaining blanks*. Here's where I'm at now:

```
IFS=$'\n' ITEMS=($(echo "$LINE" | tr "\t" "\n"))
```

The issue here is that `IFS` is one-or-more so it gobbles up new-lines, tabs, whatever. I've tried a few other things based on other questions posted here but they assume that there will always be a value in all fields, never blank. And [the one that seems to hold the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing) is far beyond me and operating on an entire file (I am just splitting a single string).

My preference here is a pure-BASH solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IFS` is only one-or-more if the characters are whitespace. Non-whitespace characters are single delimiters. So a simple solution, if there is some non-whitespace character which you are confident is not in your string, is to translate tabs to that character and then split on it:

```
IFS=$'\2' read -ra ITEMS <<<"${LINE//$'\t'/$'\2'}"
```

Unfortunately, assumptions like "there is no instance of `\2` in the input" tend to fail in the long-run, where "in the long-run" translates to "at the worst possible time". So you might want to do it in two steps:

```
IFS=$'\2' read -ra TEMP < <(tr $'\t\2' $'\2\t' <<<"$LINE")
ITEMS=("${TEMP[@]//$'\t'/$'\2'}")
```

Comment: A very elegant solution.  By the way, for reference, the thing about sequences of IFS whitespace characters being treated as a delimiter is mentioned [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility: instead of splitting with `IFS`, use the `-d` option to `read` tab-terminated "lines" from the string. However, you need to ensure that your string *ends* with a tab as well, or you will lose the last item.

```
items=()
while IFS='' read -r -d$'\t' x; do
   items+=( "$x" )
done <<< $'   foo   \t  bar\nbaz \t   foobar\t'

printf "===%s===\n" "${items[@]}"
```

Ensuring a trailing tab without adding an extra field can be accomplished with

```
if [[ $str != *$'\t' ]]; then str+=$'\t'; fi
```

if necessary.

Comment: It's funny, I saw the `-d` and tried to make something of it myself unsuccessfully; I see the key was using a loop (I tried combining with `-a`). One question: why do you set `IFS=''` beforehand?

Comment: It's necessary if one of the tab-delimited strings starts or ends with whitespace, as `read` would strip that before setting the value of `x` with the default value of `IFS`.

Comment: To cope with a missing trailing newline, you can replace your `read` statement in the while test by `IFS='' read -r -d$'\t' x || [[ $x ]]`, or just add `items+=( "$x" )` after the while loop.

Comment: `items+=("$x")` after the loop will append an empty string if the file *isn't* missing the final newline, so you'd need a guard like `(( $? )) && items+=("$x")`. (Not tested, and there are tricky corner cases, so I'm not sure that's 100% correct.)

Answer (score 0):

IFS Special Characters:

```
Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
ANSI  C  standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
as follows:
       \a     alert (bell)
       \b     backspace
       \e
       \E     an escape character
       \f     form feed
       \n     new line
       \r     carriage return
       \t     horizontal tab
       \v     vertical tab
       \\     backslash
       \'     single quote
       \"     double quote
       \?     question mark
       \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is  the  octal  value
              nnn (one to three digits)
       \xHH   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the hexadecimal
              value HH (one or two hex digits)
       \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is  the
              hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
       \UHHHHHHHH
              the  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the
              hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
       \cx    a control-x character
```

The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the  dollar  sign  had  not
   been present.

A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause
   the string to be translated according to the current  locale.   If  the
   current  locale  is  C  or  POSIX,  the dollar sign is ignored.  If the
   string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Answer (score -1):

```
line=$'zero\tone\ttwo'
IFS=$'\t' read -a arr <<< "${line}"
declare -p
```

Output is

```
declare -a arr='([0]="zero" [1]="one" [2]="two")'
```

**Note.** This doesn't deal with newlines in `line`.

Answer (score -1):

A pure bash solution that will only split on tabs, and preserve newlines and other funny symbols, if any:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr -d '' < <(printf '%s' "$line")
```

Try it:

```
$ line=$'zero\tone with\nnewlines\ttwo\t     three   \n\t\tfive\n'
$ IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr -d '' < <(printf '%s' "$line")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="zero" [1]="one with
newlines" [2]="two" [3]="     three   
" [4]="five
")'
```

As you can see, this works flawlessly: it preserves everything (spaces, newlines, etc.), splits only at the tab characters.

There's one drawback: it doesn't handle “empty fields”: observe there are two consecutive tabs in `line`; we would expect to get an empty field in `arr`, but that's not the case.

There's another less obvious drawback: the return code of `read` is `1`, so technically, for Bash, there's a failure in this command. That's absolutely not a problem, unless you're using `set -e` or `set -E`, but this is not recommended anyways (so you shouldn't).

If you can live with these two minor drawbacks, this might be the ideal solution.

Note that we're using `< <(printf '%s' "$line")` and not `<<< "$line"` to feed `read`, as the latter inserts a trailing newline.