# Select mysql query with bash

Tags: mysql, bash

How to `select` mysql query with bash so each column will be in a separate array value?

I've tried the following command but it only works if the content is one word. for example:
id= 11, text=hello, important=1

if I've an article for instance in `text`. the code will not work properly. I guess I can use `cut -f -d` but if "text" contains special characters it wont work either.

```
while read -ra line; do
    id=$(echo "${line[1]}")
    text=$(echo "${line[2]}")
    important=$(echo "${line[3]}")

    echo "id: $id"
    echo "text: $text"
    echo "important: $important"

done < <(mysql -e "${selectQ}" -u${user} -p${password} ${database} -h ${host})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash by default splits strings at any whitespace character. First you need a unique column identifier for your output, you can use `mysql --batch` to get tab-separated csv output.

From the MySQL man page:

> --batch, -B
>
> Print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.
>   Batch mode results in nontabular output format and escaping of special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see   the description for the --raw option

You want the result to be escaped, so don't use `--raw`, otherwise a tab character in your result data will break the loop again.

To skip the first row (column names) you can use the option `--skip-column-names` in addition

Now you can walk through each line and split it by tab character.
You can force bash to split by tab only by overriding the IFS variable ([Internal Field Separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)) temporarily.

**Example**

```
# myread prevents collapsing of empty fields
myread() {
    local input
    IFS= read -r input || return $?
    while (( $# > 1 )); do
        IFS= read -r "$1" <<< "${input%%[$IFS]*}"
        input="${input#*[$IFS]}"
        shift
    done
    IFS= read -r "$1" <<< "$input"
 }


# loop though the result rows
while IFS=$'\t' myread id name surname url created; do
     echo "id: ${id}";
     echo "name: ${name}";
     echo "surname: ${surname}"; 
     echo "url: ${url}";
     echo "created: ${created}";
done < <(mysql --batch --skip-column-headers -e "SELECT id, name, surname, url, created FROM users")
```

**myread function** all credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing#19538478) by [Stefan Kriwanek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910671/stefan-kriwanek)

**Attention**:
You need to be very careful with quotes and variable delimiters.
If you just `echo $row[0]` without the curly brackets, you will get the wrong result

**EDIT**
You still have a problem , when a column returns empty string because the internal field separator matches any amount of the defined char:

`row1\t\trow3` will create an array `[row1,row3]` instead of `[row1,,row3]`
I found a very nice approach to fix this, updated the example above.
Also read can directly seperate the input stream into variables.

Comment: it's not as simple as I thought it would be - hold on for a actually working solution

Comment: ok, sorry for the confusion, example is working now. Make sure you use the curly brackets, that's important

Comment: Thank You! It saved me time.