# while loop variable reading issue

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file `a.txt` like this:

```
1       1       a
        2       b
4       4       d
```

Now I read that text file and feed it into a `while` loop:

```
cat a.txt | while read k l o 
do
  echo "  ${k} ${l} ${o} "
  if [ "${k}" == "${l}" ]; then
    echo  "  success ; X: ${k}  Y : ${l}  Z : ${o}   "
  else 
    echo "   failed ; X: ${k}  Y : ${l}  Z : ${o}   "
  fi
done
```

In my text file 2nd line first value is empty. That's why I'm getting y value in to x and z value in to y.

How can I handle such empty values and get all values printed at their correct positions?

Comment: Your question as it was posted was borderline incomprehensible, and also wrongly tagged `PowerShell` when the question is actually about Linux shell scripting. I rephrased and re-formatted the question for you this time. Please put some more effort of your own into your questions from now on. If you don't care about your own questions, why would anyone else?

Comment: You can't check if a particular field is empty. If all 3 fields must be present then you can check for empty strings and print error.

Comment: Please provide some more information about the input file format. Are the values separated by tabs or a given number of spaces?

Comment: given number of values are seperated by tabs

Comment: possible duplicate of [read in bash on tab-delimited file without empty fields collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just insert 0 for empty x value?
anyway you would need 3 values.. /bin/sh read command assigns the first value to the first name..