# How do I extract a single value from a tab-separated table in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract the Max value from LabelID 1 (117.96).

```
LabelID        Mean        StdD         Max         Min       Count     Vol(mm^3)        Extent(Vox)
0      20.99750    56.25956  1606.19238   -15.53062     2073413   3591156.654    144   144   100
1      98.31916     7.77291   117.95876    81.89870         110       190.520     11    15     6
3     131.89938    10.77435   154.69934   111.26049          77       133.364     11    12     4
```

I've tried using `c3d $image $ROI -lstat | awk ‘{print $22}’` but it returns an empty line. Cut produces similar results.

Comment: the max value is 190.520, not 117.

Comment: first, understand how awk is seeing your data. try `...|awk '{print $0}'`. Are you sure you want field `22`? Or try `$4` . Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I meant the Max column, not the max value in LabelID 1's row. I tried awk '{print $0}' and that returned an empty line as well. $4 yielded similar results. What does this mean?

Comment: BTW, you're missing a lot of quotes; you'll want to make this something like `c3d "$image" "$ROI" -lstat`, or you'll get unpleasant behavior when running against files with interesting names. See http://shellcheck.net/ for automated testing for that kind of bug (you can download the tool to run it locally against your own scripts; it's not just a web service).

Comment: @AbrahamBrownell, `$0` returning only empty lines most likely means that the output really is empty. Does what you get from `c3d ... | less` differ from output from `c3d` on its own?

Comment: @AbrahamBrownell, ...I'd also suggest running your actual script with `set -x` to see the actual command line it's invoking `c3d` with to compare against the one you use during manual testing; if you had a variable with surprising values, that could perhaps be responsible.

Comment: Agreed with @shellter; it's unclear why you're aiming for field $22 - it almost looks like you were counting fields starting from the beginning of the file rather than the beginning of each line.

Comment: I've written a `bash` script to do this with all kinds of commands. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692492/2452680

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just say:

```
$ awk '$1==1{print $4}' file
117.95876
```

That is, print the 4th column when 1st column is `1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
target_label=1
target_column=3 # first column is 0, so fourth is 3

while read -r -a columns; do                   # read a line into an array
  if [[ ${columns[0]} = $target_label ]]; then # check label id
    echo "${columns[target_column]}"           # print the column we want
    break                                      # and exit the loop
  fi
done <infile                                   # redirect input for that full block
```

Of course, `<infile` can be replaced with `< <(your command goes here)` to read the stream from a the output of a command rather than a file.

If you only want to accept tabs, and not any other kind of whitespace, make it `while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a columns`. If you don't want to allow multiple consecutive literal tabs to be coalesced, see [read in bash on tab-delimited file without empty fields collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing).

Comment: Beautiful solution! I don't know what the OP wants to do, but this is just so nice : )

Comment: I guess the question wasn't tagged with anything other than [tag:bash] but seems like a lot of fuss compared with just using cut / awk.

Comment: Depends on what the OP is actually doing; if one wants to actually interact between the file being read and shell state / variable contents / etc., the extra verbosity can be worth it. I'm presuming that the `echo` here is just a placeholder for more interesting logic.

Comment: (...if I didn't intend it to be a placeholder, I'd have used the more robust `printf '%s\n' "${columns[3]}"` instead).

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'NR==2{print $2}'`

The above command will extract the value where indexes [2,2].

For `awk`, the index starts from 1 not 0.
`NR==2` specifies the line number
`{print $2}` specifies the column number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script I wrote to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Flags - optional and to avoid potential conflicts
# 1st
# -n = only number for column
# -t = only text for column
# -a = any for column
# 2nd
# -n = only number for row
# -t = only text for row
# -a = any for row
nc=1; tc=1; nr=1; tr=1
if [ ${1:0:1} == "-" ]; then
    if [ ${1:1:1} == "n" ]; then
        tc=0
    elif [ ${1:1:1} == "t" ]; then
        nc=1
    fi
    if [ ${1:2:1} == "n" ]; then
        tr=0
    elif [ ${1:2:1} == "t" ]; then
        nr=1
    fi
    shift
fi

command="$1"
# Number or text value
column="$2"
row="$3"
ltrim="$4"
rtrim="$5"

columnNo=-1
rowNo=-1

exec < /dev/null

while read -r -a columns; do
    (( rowNo++ ))
    if (( columnNo == -1 )); then
        total="${#columns[@]}"
        columnNo=$(for (( i=0; i<$total; i++ ))
        {
            if [[ "${columns[$i]}" == "$column" ]] || [[ "$column" == "$i" ]]; then
                echo "$i"
                break
            elif (( i >= total - 1 )); then
                echo -1
                break
            fi
        })
    else
        if [[ "${columns[0]}" == "$row" && "$tr" == 1 ]] || [[ "$rowNo" -eq "$row" && "$nr" == 1 ]]; then
            str="${columns[columnNo]}"
            str=${str#"$ltrim"}
            str=${str%"$rtrim"}
            echo "$str"
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
done < <($command 2> /dev/null)
echo "Error! Could not be found."
exit 1
```

It accepts an optional flag, followed by 3 to 5 parameters, as follows; the command, the column, the row, optionally, and optionally `ltrim` and `rtrim` values.

Eg:

```
./extract-table-entry.sh "yum upgrade nginx" "Version" "mginx"
# Output = Error! Could not be found.
./extract-table-entry.sh "yum upgrade nginx" "Version" "nginx"
# Output = 1:1.22.1-1.el8.ngx
./extract-table-entry.sh "ls -la" 8 4
# Output = someDir

# When the data is stored as a file, use `cat`
ls -la > file.txt
./extract-table-entry.sh "cat file.txt" 8 4
# Output = someDir
```

To format the output and use only text for the column and row:

```
./extract-table-entry.sh -tt "yum upgrade nginx" "Version" "nginx" "1:" ".ngx"
# Output = 1.22.1-1.el8
```

It works when the output contains more than one table, or the output contains extra text that isn't part of the table.