# Replace '\n' with white space only when the occurrence of '\t' is more than a number

Tags: awk, sed

I have tens of thousands of tab-delimited data files, each like:

```
a0\ta1\ta2\ta3\ta4\ta5\ta6\ta7\ta8\ta9\n
b0\tb1\tb2\tb3\tb4\tb5\tb6\tb7\tb8\tb9\n
...
```

However, occasionally there are files containing (randomly) malformed lines like:

```
a0\ta1\ta2\ta3_0\n
a3_1\ta4\ta5\ta6\ta7\ta8\ta9\n
b0\tb1\tb2_0\n
b2_1\tb3\tb4\tb5\tb6\tb7\tb8\tb9\n
...
```

where `a3_0`, `a3_1` (`b2_0`, `b2_1` resp.) are parts of `a3` (`b2` resp.) originally separated by a white space. I want to replace each `\n` at the end of a line with a white space only when that line is too short, or, too few `\t`. Currently `5` seems to be a safe threshold.

I often use `sed` to do some modifications, which are much simpler than the above. I am wondering if `sed` or some other commands (like `awk`? which I still need to learn) can be used for fast processing (since I have many files). Thanks.

Comment: Inasmuch as this is a question about finding a solution with good performance characteristics -- How large are the files? How many are there? Do you care more about startup time or throughput within an individual file? (If they're short, it may cost more to start up an instance of a tool per file; if they're long, it would cost more to use an inefficient / poorly-chosen tool for throughput purposes).

Comment: +Charles Duffy Each file is very small, only several KB. But I have tens of thousands of them.

Comment: Hmm. From a throughput perspective, `awk` tends to have much better performance than `sed`. However, it doesn't have in-place editing support unless you're using GNU awk newer than 4.1.0 -- which version do you have?

Comment: (Also, native bash is often an acceptable choice for small files -- it's slow on a per-line basis, but if well-written has effectively no overhead spent on tool startup times).

Comment: To be clear, btw, you mean **literal** `\t` and `\n` strings, two characters each, first of those characters being a backslash? Or are you using `\t` as standin for a tab and `\n` for a newline?

Comment: It seems I have 4.2.1, but I may need it portable for others.

Comment: They are not literal, but tab and newline. These files are tab-delimited data files (like .tsv).

Comment: Gotcha. My answer isn't ideal from a throughput perspective (the bash `read` builtin operates a character at a time and so isn't the fastest thing in the world), but to write a performance-focused `awk` answer I'd want to be able to depend on modern gawk (since without extensions, running `awk` once per file, you'll be paying a lot in startup costs).

Comment: (...and actually, even as it is, my answer is paying startup costs for `mktemp` and `mv`; however, eliminating the former compromises security, and eliminating the latter requires a shell within a builtin implementation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT` (and later `-i infile` and `ENDFILE`) and using commas instead of tabs for visibility:

```
$ cat file
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
a0,a1,a2,a3_0
a3_1,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2_0
b2_1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9

$ awk -v RS='([^,]*,){9}[^\n]*\n' '{$0=RT; sub(/\n$/,"") gsub(/\n/," ")} 1' file
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
a0,a1,a2,a3_0 a3_1,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2_0 b2_1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
```

The above [ab-]uses RS to describe each record (instead of the record separator) as a series of 10 comma-separated fields ending with a newline and then replaces the newlines as appropriate within each record before printing.

Just change `RS='([^,]*,){9}[^\n]*\n'` to `RS='([^\t]*\t){9}[^\n]*\n'` for it to work with tab-separated instead of comma-separated fields.

To make the changes to all files add `-i inplace`:

```
awk -i inplace -v RS='...' '...' *
```

or:

```
find ... -exec awk -i inplace -v RS='...' '...' {} +
```

You actually don't even have to hard-code the RS, the tool could figure it out, assuming there's at least 1 complete line in each input file:

```
$ awk -F',' '
    BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
    NR==FNR { n=(NF>n?NF:n); next }
    ENDFILE { RS="([^"FS"]*"FS"){"n-1"}[^\n]*\n" }
    { $0=RT; sub(/\n$/,"") gsub(/\n/," "); print }
' file
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
a0,a1,a2,a3_0 a3_1,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2_0 b2_1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
```

Just change `-F','` to `-F'\t'` for tab-separated.

FYI with POSIX awks, the closest equivalents of the above two gawk scripts would be:

```
$ awk '
    { rec=rec $0 RS }
    END{
        while ( match(rec,/([^,]*,){9}[^\n]*\n/) ) {
            tgt = substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            sub(/\n$/,"",tgt)
            gsub(/\n/," ",tgt)
            print tgt
            rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
' file
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
a0,a1,a2,a3_0 a3_1,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2_0 b2_1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
```

and:

```
awk -F',' '
    { rec=rec $0 RS; n=(NF>n?NF:n) }
    END{
        while ( match(rec,"([^"FS"]*"FS"){"n-1"}[^\n]*\n") ) {
            tgt = substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            sub(/\n$/,"",tgt)
            gsub(/\n/," ",tgt)
            print tgt
            rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
' file
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
a0,a1,a2,a3_0 a3_1,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9
b0,b1,b2_0 b2_1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9
```

Just be aware that those read the whole file into a single string before the main processing begins so they'd fail if your file was too huge to fit in memory but you already told us each file is "very small" so that shouldn't be an issue.

To overwrite the input file the simplest approach is always:

```
awk '{...}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

but in this case you can alternatively do:

```
awk '{...} END{... print tgt > ARGV[1] ...}' file
```

That works in this case because awk has already completed reading the input file before starting the END section. Do not attempt it elsewhere in the script.

Comment: I would have gone here, but tho OP expressed concern about limiting support to current `gawk` releases (see comment history on the question).

Comment: Ah, yup I see that - I've added a POSIX equivalent at the end now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you name the following script `repiece`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\t'       # use tab separators throughout this script
rIFS=,          # except to avoid field coalescing, use commas
pieces_needed=5 # adjust this to taste

for arg; do
  tempfile="${arg}.tmp-$$" # vulnerable to symlink attacks; use mktemp instead if untrusted
                           # users have write access to current directory.
  deferred=( )
  {
    while IFS="$rIFS" read -r -a pieces; do
      if (( ( ${#deferred[@]} + ${#pieces[@]} ) < pieces_needed )); then
        deferred+=( "${pieces[@]}" )
      elif (( ${#deferred[@]} )); then
        # separate last piece of deferred and first of pieces with a space
        all_pieces=( "${deferred[@]} ${pieces[@]}" )
        printf '%s\n' "${all_pieces[*]}"
        deferred=( )
      else
        printf '%s\n' "${pieces[*]}"
      fi
    done
    # if we have anything deferred for the last line, print it now
    (( ${#deferred[@]} )) && printf '%s\n' "${deferred[*]}"
  } < <(tr -- "$IFS" "$rIFS" <"$arg") >"$tempfile"
  mv -- "$tempfile" "$arg"
done
```

...you can invoke the smallest possible number of invocations to process all your files as follows:

```
# if your files end in .tsv
find . -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec ./repiece {} +
```

Comment: Thanks. But there seem to be two bugs after I used your script. Firstly, the `\n` is replaced by a `\t` instead of a white space. Secondly, there are empty fields in my files, e.g. `\t\t\t\t\ta5\ta6\ta7\ta8\ta9`. The script has removed all the proceeding `\t` (although I would like to keep them). I have also noticed sometimes two lines are joined together, even though they are already long enough.

Comment: Re: the empty tabs being removed, that's actually a fairly sticky one, enough that I asked my own question about it some years ago -- see [read in bash on tab-delimited file without empty fields collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing). The tersest answers there require a non-space character to use temporarily in place of a tab -- if I used a comma, for instance, are you comfortably that those don't exist as literals anywhere in the data?

Comment: (a tab **is** a form of whitespace, btw, so this answer *is* responsive already on the other count -- but if you want a non-tab space, that's doable too).

Comment: I've edit to work around the empty-field issue. As for "sometimes two lines are joined together, even though they are already long enough" -- please provide a reproducer for that.

Comment: It seems to work well now. Just two minor issues. The last `\t` will be removed if there is a `\t\n` at the end of a line. But this is OK since it does not affect my later processing. The `,` is not that safe (and this gave me pain before), so I make `rIFS=,,,`. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: `rIFS=,,,` doesn't actually help you -- `IFS` specifies a collection of characters, not an arbitrary string to act as a separator; `IFS=,,,` and `IFS=,` both have the exact same effect. Thus, you need to find **a single character** that can be used as a separator, or adopt one of the other, longer approaches from the linked question.

Comment: I changed `,,,` to `+`, which seems OK now.

Answer (score 1):

In awk, changing the `ORS` between a space and `\ņ`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS=OFS="\t"       # set field separators
    RS=ORS="\n"       # set record separators
}
NF<=5 {               # if below or at threshold
    ORS=" "           # redefine output record separator
}
{
    print             # print record with ORS
    ORS="\n"          # reset ORS back to newline
}' file
a0      a1      a2      a3      a4      a5      a6      a7      a8      a9
b0      b1      b2      b3      b4      b5      b6      b7      b8      b9
a0      a1      a2      a3_0 a3_1       a4      a5      a6      a7      a8      a9
b0      b1      b2_0 b2_1       b3      b4      b5      b6      b7      b8      b9
```

Processing multiple files with shell scripting:

```
$ for f in file1 file2 ; do awk ... $f > new-$f ; done
```

Quote `$f` if needed.

Comment: Why only quote "if needed"? Writing code with practices you *know* can't handle all possible input data seems rather perverse, no? (I trot this out rather often, but the worst data loss event I've seen was caused by an "impossible" wildcard in a filename -- due to a bug dumping random memory contents into a buffer used to create said name -- to be expanded).

Comment: Know your data.

Comment: "Knowing your data" means knowing the future. It means knowing every possible bug a not-yet-written producer for the content you're reading will ever have. It means knowing every specification change that hasn't yet taken place. You're encouraging people to do the impossible, and telling them they should do the possible as a replacement for following best practices and writing unconditionally robust code.

Comment: Sure. I'm not advicing people here to prepare for everything and taking responsibility for whatever they do in the future. _Quote if needed_ is my disclaimer. In this case I try to show op how to use awk for what he was trying to do. I even skipped the `awk ... $f > tmp && mv -i tmp $f` so that hw won't overwrite his data. If he want's boilerplated bash script, I'm not answering that question, I'll leave it happily to you, sir.

Comment: If I'm building a system on top of pieces that were written only with the data that was expected when each piece was written, that overall larger system is brittle and requires immense, unreasonable testing effort to expand: Every part of it is prone to breaking when the assumptions in place when that component was written change. And assumptions *do* change -- that's part of the reality of building, deploying and maintaining software in the real world.

Comment: (As another example: I've been burned far too many times by folks who assumed that they could hand-parse an XML or JSON document with assumptions about element order and namespace continuing to hold making brittle, fragile systems that couldn't deal with extended inputs, even when those extensions would have been perfectly safe if consumers were written in a way that honored standards for the relevant document formats; consequently, I've been places where we've had to version and maintain old APIs when the only changes were just adding extra data w/o removing or changing anything).

Comment: ...so, pulling out "know your data" triggers grumpiness that goes well beyond quoting/filenames.

Comment: Apparently. Good night, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\t/&/9;t;N;s/\n/ /;ta' file
```

If there are less than 9 tabs in the current line, append the next line and replace the newline by a space. Repeat until 9 or more tabs.