# read TSV file line-by-line with blank columns

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm trying to read a TSV (tab separated) file line-by-line and process certain columns.  This code fails when a column is blank, because it offsets the remaining columns by one.  How can I make `read` handle a blank column correctly?

```
input_file="day1.ale"
while IFS=$'\t' read Name Tracks Start End Take Tape UNC FPS Reel Scene
do
echo $FPS
done < $input_file
```

Here is a link to a sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/isxirf90jpdyp0p/day1.ale?dl=0

I should mention I am using MacOS Sierra, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You do know that `day1.ale` has DOS `CRLF` line ends?

Comment: I hadn't thought about it, but I don't see why that would matter in this situation

Comment: Other than file size, it shouldn't affect read with `IFS='\t'`, but I found it really strange. I read and dumped both versions (original and one run through `dos2unix`) and at least on Linux, `read` just spits out the `CRLF`, but I don't know about mac, since mac (pre-OSX) used `CR` for the line end...

Comment: Also note your heading line ends in a `tab` before the double `CRLF` `CRLF` (e.g. `000000e0  53 4f 4c 56 45 5f 53 49  5a 49 4e 47 09 0d 0a 0d  |SOLVE_SIZING....|` ... `000000f0  0a`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to answer my own question like this:

```
input_file="day1.ale"
input_data=$(cat $input_file | tr \\11 \\7) # replace tabs with alarm bell
while IFS=$'\a' read Name Tracks Start End Take Tape UNC FPS Reel Scene
do
echo $FPS
done <<< "$input_data"
```

This question is nearly a duplicate of [read in bash on tab-delimited file without empty fields collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing), but the answer is slightly different because of the while loop.  Not sure if I should delete the question or not.