# Bourne Script process tab delimited file & replace empty tab variables

Tags: shell, sh

I have a file that is tab-delimited and I need to access each tab. Most of the time each tab will have a string & that is easy enough with AWK. However, sometimes the tabs will be empty & I'm not sure how to change them. I need to replace the empty tab that would be there with an "x". I've tried sed, awk, and even a counter with a while loop. My current attempt is using an if loop to test for " ". Not sure what to do..
Thanks.

```
middlename=$(cat $1 | awk '{print $3}')

if test $middlename = " "
then
        echo "yes"
fi
```

Comment: Quibble: `/bin/sh` is not Bourne on any modern system, it's POSIX sh. To distinguish between the two, you can use the same technique GNU Autotools does: Check whether `^` acts as a pipe character. In 1970s-era Bourne, `echo hello ^ cat` will emit `hello`, whereas in 1990s-era POSIX sh and compliant derivatives thereof, it will emit `hello ^ cat`.

Comment: Anyhow, you need more quotes, which http://shellcheck.net/ will tell you without needing to involve humans. `if test "$middlename" = ""`, for instance, will do nicely.

Comment: That didn't work, the file data looks like this.

Comment: tom<tab>"blank"<tab>henry<tab>dept<tab>num I need to access that blank.

Comment: Gotcha. I actually filed a question asking about that way back in the day -- [read in bash on tab-delimited file without empty fields collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622355/read-in-bash-on-tab-delimited-file-without-empty-fields-collapsing). The [answer by DigitalRoss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622458/14122) that suggests using `tr` with a non-whitespace delimiter will work for you here in `/bin/sh` land, so long as such a delimiter (that can't be found in your data) exists.

Answer (score 0):

`awk`, by default, splits its input on arbitrary runs of whitespace, so "blank" isn't going to be one of the input fields unless you change the field separator to be *exactly* one tab.

```
middlename=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2}')
```

Then, as already mentioned, you need to quote the parameter expansion to avoid the value from being discarded.

```
if test "$middlename" = " "; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```